# Docker container with build output and no source

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a build process that converts typescript into javascript, minifies and concatenates css files, etc.

I would like to put those files into an nginx docker container, but I don't want the original javascript / css source to be included, nor the tools that I use to build them. Is there a good way to do this, or do I have to run the build outside docker (or in a separately defined container), then COPY the relevant files in?

[This page](http://blog.terranillius.com/post/docker_builder_pattern/) talks about doing something similar in a manual way, but doesn't explain how to automate the process e.g. with docker-compose or something.

Comment: An example using `dobi` (disclaimer, I am the author of this tool) to automate this process: https://github.com/dnephin/dobi/tree/master/examples/minimal-docker-image. `dobi` was designed for exactly these kinds of tasks. Compose is not really designed for these kind of project build tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest version of docker supports multi-stage builds where build products can be copied from on container to another.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a docker images with all required tools to build your code also that can clone code and build it. After build it have to copy
   into docker volume for example volume name is `/opt/webapp`.
2. Launch build docker container using build image in step 1

   ```
   docker run -d -P --name BuildContainer -v /opt/webapp:/opt/webapp build_image_name
   ```
3. Launch `nginx` docker container that will use shared volume of build docker in which your build code resides.

   ```
   docker run -d -P --name Appserver -v /opt/webapp:/usr/local/nginx/html nginx_image_name
   ```
4. After building and shipping your build code to Appserver . you can delete `BuildContainer` because that is no more required.

**Advantage of above steps:**

1. your build code will in host machine so if one `Appserver` docker fail or stop then your build code will be safe in host machine and you can launch new docker using that build code.
2. if you create docker image  for building code then every time no need to install required tool while launching docker.
3. you can build your code in host machine also but if you want your code should be build in fresh environment every time then this will be good. or  if you use same host machine to build/compile code every time then some older source code may create problem or git clone error etc.

**EDIT:**

you can append `:ro` (Read only) to volume by which one container will not affect another. you can Read more about docker volume [Here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/) . Thanks @BMitch for suggestion.

Comment: Interesting design. If doing this, consider mounting the volume read only (append `:ro` to the volume mount) so that one running container cannot impact another.

Comment: You can do something very similar to this without using a volume for the second image ("nginx" in this example). That way your compiled artifacts are included in the target image and can be distributed along with it. https://github.com/dnephin/dobi/tree/master/examples/minimal-docker-image is an example of how to do this with `dobi` which is a tool created specifically for this kind of thing.

Comment: @dnephin Could you add a separate answer about this. We want build products to be contained in the image so that it is more self contained. I keep having to tell people "look at the second comment in this answer" instead of "look at this answer".

Answer (score 2):

This is an ideal scenario for a multi-stage build. You perform the compiling in the first stage, copy the output of that compile to the second stage, and only ship that second stage. Each stage is an independent image that begins with a `FROM` line. And to transfer files between stages, there's now a `COPY --from` syntax. The result looks roughly like:

```
# first stage with your full compile environment, e.g. maven/jdk
FROM maven as build

WORKDIR /src
COPY src /src
RUN mvn install

# second stage starts below with just a jre base image
FROM openjdk:jre

# copy the jar from the first stage here
COPY --from=build /src/result.jar /app
CMD java -jar /app/result.jar
```

---

Original answer:

Two common options:

- As mentioned, you can build outside and copy the compiled result into the container.
- You merge your download, build, and cleanup step into a single `RUN` command. This is a common best practice to minimize the size of each layer.

An example Dockerfile for the second option would look like:

```
FROM mybase:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install tools \
    && git clone https://github.com/myproj \
    && cd myproj \
    && make \
    && make install
    && cd .. \
    && apt-get rm tools && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf myproj
```

The lines would be a little more complicated than that, but that's the gist.

Comment: Option 2 doesn't seem viable. Download, build, cleanup is things like install NodeJS, install loads of tools and dependencies, then uninstall them all again.

Comment: If you don't want them in the image but you want your image entirely self contained (just run `docker build` anywhere), that's the only solution to your request. Option 1 happens fairly often for statically linked binaries, your build simply includes 2 parts, outside and inside of Docker. The separate build could be a docker container that outputs its results via a host volume when run, and you then you import that result in your final image with option 1.

Answer (score 0):

As @dnephin suggested in his comments on the question and on @pl_rock's answer, the standard docker tools are not designed to do this, but you can use a third party tool like one of the following:

- [dobi](https://github.com/dnephin/dobi) (48 GitHub stars)
- [packer](https://www.packer.io/) (6210 GitHub stars)
- [rocker](https://github.com/grammarly/rocker) (759 GitHub stars)
- [conveyor](https://github.com/remind101/conveyor) (152 GitHub stars)

(GitHub stars correct when I wrote the answer)

We went with dobi as it was the first one we heard of (because of this question), but it looks like packer is the most popular.

Answer (score -1):

Create a docker file to run your build process, then run cleanup code

Example:

```
FROM node:latest

# Provides cached layer for node_modules
ADD package.json /tmp/package.json

RUN cd /tmp && npm install
RUN mkdir -p /dist && cp -a /tmp/node_modules /dist/
RUN cp /tmp/package.json /dist

ADD . /tmp

RUN cd /tmp && npm run build
RUN mkdir -p /dist && cp -a /tmp/. /dist

#run some clean up code here
RUN npm run cleanup

# Define working directory
WORKDIR /dist    

# Expose port
EXPOSE 4000

# Run app
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

In your docker compose file

```
web:
  build: ../project_path
  environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
  restart: always
  ports:
    - "4000"
```

Comment: By doing this as separate RUN commands, you create layers with all the build tools included and then remove them in the following layers. The result is the image is much larger and takes longer to send over the network even though the files no longer exist.

Comment: Hi @BMitch, do you have docs to tell about this, I'm beginner to learn docker. I need to know more about execute multiple RUN command cause large image. Thanks

Comment: @TrietNguyen Docker's best practices: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/. There's also a docker build and intro presentation in my repo (be sure to see the speaker notes with P): https://github.com/sudo-bmitch/presentations/